# How can i change ip in mail probing using perl

Tags: linux, perl, email, smtp, cpan

I am creating a script for checking mail id inbox exist or not (mail probing), i am using Mail::CheckUser module for this.but the problem is when i continuously run the script, there may be a chance to block my ip , so i would like to use change my ip simultaneously. i have server with 10 ips attached , i would like to use this ips randomly,please give me any idea

code i am using is given below

```
 use Mail::CheckUser;
 use Data::Dumper;

 my $res = Mail::CheckUser::check_email('xxxxx@example.com');
 print $res."\n\n\n";

 my $res1 = Mail::CheckUser::last_check();

 print Dumper($res1)."\n\n";
```

thanks for any help

Comment: mailprobing is abusive and does not work in many cases. there is a reason recipient servers will block you for trying to do that repeatedly. you're basically asking the SO community how to snowshoe. please don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO It requires simple patch of `Mail::CheckUser`.

Mail::CheckUser uses Net::SMTP to handle smtp connections. Net::SMTP constructor (`new` sub) supports LocalAddr parameter you need **BUT** I can see no way in present code of Mail::CheckUser to pass extra parameters to New::SMTP construtor.

http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ILYAM/Mail-CheckUser-1.21/CheckUser.pm
http://search.cpan.org/~shay/libnet-1.23/Net/SMTP.pm

Comment: Thanks Andrzej for replay.Could you please suggest a method for mail probing using  perl on changing ips.?